# Laravel Jobs Queue

Tags: laravel, fila

Estou com uma dúvida, estou tentando executar os jobs usando o Supervisor para rodar jobs simultaneos, só que o comando não funciona com *php artisan queue:work* e sim com *php artisan queue:work --queue=high,Migration*
Estou usando o QUEUE_DRIVER como database, mas não acho que isso interfira... o comando que eu adiciono os jobs na fila é

```
\App\Jobs\S3Migration::dispatch($file)->onQueue('Migration');
```

Eu executo a página que tem esse código e adiciona tudo para a fila, só que se a configuração do Supervisor chamar o *php artisan queue:work* não funciona, apenas rodando com *php artisan queue:work --queue=high,Migration*... será que é algo que tenho que colocar para que execute as tarefas? ou alguma outra configuração que tenho que colocar no Supervisor?

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de fazer alguns meses, imagino que você já achou a resposta, de qualquer modo, fica aqui a resposta.

Você está "despachando" para um queue específico, no caso o queue "Migration", por isso que o `php artisan queue:work`, por padrão, despacha usando o "default queue", contudo, dá para alterar o comportamento padrão, alterando o arquivo `app/Console/Kernel.php`.

Conforme documentação sobre [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues)

```
// This job is sent to the default queue...
Job::dispatch();

// This job is sent to the "emails" queue...
Job::dispatch()->onQueue('emails');
```

Não é um artigo muito completo mas me ajudou em algumas dúvidas iniciais sobre queues e jobs. [Scheduler: Queues – Multiple Queues](http://laravel.at.jeffsbox.eu/laravel-5-queues-multiple-queues)

Comment: opa, resolvi, na verdade estou gerenciando pelo Laravel Horizon e no config do horizon defino as minhas Queues

Answer (score 0):

Estou usando o Laravel Horizon para o gerenciamento das Queues

```
 'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default','Migration','Upload'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 3,
            'tries' => 3,
        ],
    ],
```